# How to hide specific column in model/entity in Symfony 4

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, doctrine

I have User entity with basic fields `id, firstname, lastname and password` in Symfony 4 Doctrine orm. What is the simplest way to hide password field using `find()` method? For example in Laravel model we can do it like this

```php
class User extends Model {

protected $hidden = ['password']
...
```

I cant find suitable solution without `select()` edit.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Laravel still have a much simpler aproach to deal with Json & serialisation thanks to its EloquentCollections ...etc

But also in Symfony (4 and higher) you can ignore fields using the `@Ignore()` annotation.

More details here : [ignoring fields](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#option-1-using-ignore-annotation)

Hope you find it helpfull.

Comment: I don't see what this answer brings that my answer from 2 years ago didn't bring. The ignore annotation is talked of right below the serialization groups section I linked to. You could have just left a comment, instead of putting a down vote on my answer. Talk about bad mentality

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, and if you specify the fields through select, you won't get entities but rather an array of data.

The proper way in my opinion (if your end goal is to filter what is sent to your view) would be to retrieve your whole entity, then serialize it (if it's not already done) and exclude the properties you don't want using serialization groups. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#attributes-groups

Note that if you're making an API, there are ready-to-go solutions to handle these cases ( FOSRestBundle being one of them : https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html )